# Hide action bar spinner items in full screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fullscreen

I have an action bar with a couple items. If user presses the spinner buttons, the items will show, as expected. Then an event is causing the screen to go "Full screen", for which the action bar, along with the spinner will hide. The problem is that the items stay and won't go away until user taps somewhere in the screen, as you can see from the screenshots below.

This is what I'm using to go fullscreen:

```
mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
mActivity.getActionBar().hide();
```

The question is, how do I work around this? Doesn't sound normal to me that the spinner items don't disappear...

[image]

Comment: have you tried changing navigation mode of the activity? getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Spinner's performclick method :

[Try this answer](http://devmobapps.blogspot.fr/2011/09/bug-in-android-or-problem-with-spinner.html)